# Overflow JLabel into Another JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Let's say I have a `JLabel` sized `20x20`. Now let's say I add the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." This sentence is too long for the `JLabel`, so it gets replaces with `...`. Is there a way that I could get it to overflow to another `JLabel`, so that the first `JLabel` would have "The quick brown fox" and the second `JLabel` would have "jumps over the lazy dog."?

---

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
lbl.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
add(lbl)
```

Produces a label that says "...".

Comment: You can create a multilined JLabel by using HTML with <br> tags.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but let's say I have one label on one side of the window and one on the other side. This feature would be similar to the Word or Pages feature that automatically overflows

Comment: A second label, on the opposite side of the page/form from the first label, that will display the overflowed text from the first?  I'm trying to imagine that, but can't. Could you whip up some ASCII art, or perhaps show a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: And, why are you setting a maximum size on the label? Perhaps if there's a better way to avoid doing this, then the original problem will also go away.

Comment: As I was saying above (before a friend shut down my computer), there is a feature of word processors that lets you link text fields so that if you type too much text in one box it automatically sends it to another box. See here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/publisher-help/flow-pasted-text-to-the-next-page-or-text-box-HP001155041.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer if you provided some more information.

I'm assuming that what you want is two labels that can be placed side by side, or in any other layout. In case the first label's text overflows, the second label will display the remainder.

Here's a solution:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.lang.Override;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        super("Test overflowing label");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(200, 200);
        setSize(300, 200);
        createUI();
    }

    private void createUI() {
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
        JLabel label1 = new OverflowingLabel("text to truncate since it's too long ...", label2);

        final JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, label1, label2);
        splitPane.setDividerSize(2);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                splitPane.setDividerLocation(.5d);
            }
        });

        setContentPane(splitPane);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test test = new Test();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class OverflowingLabel extends JLabel  {

        private JLabel[] dependantLabels;

        public OverflowingLabel(String text, JLabel... dependantLabels) {
            super(text);
            this.dependantLabels = dependantLabels;

            addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                    overflowText();
                }

                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    overflowText();
                }
            });
        }

        private void overflowText() {
            int index = getIndexToChopText();

            String text = getText().substring(index);

            for (JLabel dependantLabel : dependantLabels)
                dependantLabel.setText(text);
        }

        private int getIndexToChopText() {
            Dimension size = getSize();
            FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
            String text = getText();

            int index = 0;
            int width = 0;

            while ((index < text.length()) && (width < size.width)) {
                int charWidth = metrics.charWidth(text.charAt(index));

                if ((width + charWidth) > size.width)
                    break;

                index ++;
                width += charWidth;
            }

            return index;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            Dimension size = super.getMinimumSize();
            return new Dimension(0, size.height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
            Rectangle clip = g2d.getClipBounds();

            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(clip.x, clip.y, clip.width, clip.height);
            g2d.setColor(getForeground());
            g2d.setFont(getFont());

            FontMetrics metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int baseLine = metrics.getAscent() + metrics.getLeading();

            int index = getIndexToChopText();

            g2d.drawString(getText().substring(0, index), 0, (getHeight() + baseLine) / 2 - 1);

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some screen shots to demonstrate the behavior:

[image]
[image]
[image]